# extracting nested values from JSON using Ruby

Tags: json, ruby

I want to extract the individual values by key out of this JSON.

```
json = JSON.parse({ "streams": [ { "index": 0, "codec_name": "mpeg2video"} ] })
```

Using `json['streams'].each do |codec_name|` returns the whole first array back.  I also tried identifying specific array number by `json['streams'][1].each do |codec_name|` and that errors.

Final output should return "mpeg2video"?

Comment: [JSON::parse](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse) requires a string as an argument: `h = JSON.parse('{ "streams": [ { "index": 0, "codec_name": "mpeg2video"} ] }') #=> {"streams"=>[{"index"=>0, "codec_name"=>"mpeg2video"}]}`. Thus, `h["streams"].first["codec_name"] #=>
"mpeg2video"`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you appear to have an array of hashes in your JSON, you need to target the key `codec_name`. This should work:

```
# Assuming json_hash is a Hash that was returned by `JSON.parse()`
json_hash = { "streams": [ { "index": 0, "codec_name": "mpeg2video"} ] }
json_hash['streams'].each { |j| j['codec_name'] }
```

In this loop `j` is targeting the hash, and therefore you need `j['codec_name']`

Comment: This returns the whole Array back.
 [ { "index": 0, "codec_name": "mpeg2video"} ]

Comment: It appears you did not test, as your first line raises the exception, `'TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into String'` (which pinpoints the problem).

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked.  Had to drill down through the Array and Hash to get to it.

```
((json[''].each { |j| j['streams'] })[0])["codec_name"]
```